# Ramsey-Turan number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The following parameter (motivated by Ramsey's and Turan's theorem) in extremal graph theory is defined as:

$RT(n, k, \ell) = \max\{|E(G)|:G=(V,E)$ with $|V| = n, \alpha(G) < k$ and $\omega(G) < \ell \}$

How can I write $ex(n, K_t)$ as $RT(.,.,.)$? For which parameter is $RT(.,.,.)$ according to Ramsey's theorem trivial?

Comment: Even if this is your own work, providing context is still important. Please consider improving your question (e.g. add your own thoughts, or motivation to the problem, etc.).

Comment: I would love to provide more context but I have absolutely no idea. This is part of my last homework this semester and I really need to get the points, I won't be able to write the final exam if I don't. I would reeaally appreciate any help.

Comment: $\alpha(G) < k$ is the largest number of independent edges and $\omega(G) < \ell \}$ is the clique number

Comment: Is $ex(n, K_t) = RT(n,n,t)$?

Comment: I noticed after I answered that this is an exact duplicate of [Writing ex(n,Kt) as RT(.,.,.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479826/91818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is mostly just knowing what the definitions are.  The definitions appear to be:

- $\mathrm{ex}(n,K_t)$ is the maximum number of edges of a graph on $n$ vertices not containing $K_t$ as a subgraph;
- $\mathrm{RT}(n, k, \ell)$ is the maximum number of edges of a graph on $n$ vertices with [independence number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependenceNumber.html) less than $k$ and [clique number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliqueNumber.html) less than $\ell$;
- the independence number $\alpha(G)$ is the cardinality of the largest independent vertex set of $G$; and
- the clique number $\omega(G)$ is the number of vertices in a maximum clique of $G$.

The number $\mathrm{ex}(n,K_t)$ is related to $K_t$-free graphs, or in other words, graphs with clique number $<t$; it places no restrictions on the independence number.  So the relationship is basically [as you say](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480476/ramsey-turan-number#comment9394826_4480476):
$$
\mathrm{ex}(n,K_t) = \mathrm{RT}(n, n+1, t)
$$
but we need to set the parameter $k$ to be greater than $n$, since the definition of $\mathrm{RT}$ restricts to graphs $G$ with $\alpha(G) < k$.